# How to remove specific attribute in mxcell

Tags: mxgraph

I have a user object for which i have set attribute.
for setting the attribute i used

```
cell.setAttribute("firstName", "john")
```

but now i want to delete the attribute or remove it. 
But there is no function to remove the attribute.

can anyone please help me to delete the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of setAttribute you can find:

```
mxCell.prototype.setAttribute = function(name, value)
{
    var userObject = this.getValue();

    if (userObject != null &&
        userObject.nodeType == mxConstants.NODETYPE_ELEMENT)
    {
        userObject.setAttribute(name, value);
    }
};
```

My suggestion would be to do the same: get the userObject with getValue first and then, considering it a regular node, use the removeAttribute function.

EDIT:

Further elaborating... You can implement your own "removeAttribute" function:

```
mxCell.prototype.removeAttribute = function(name)
{
    var userObject = this.getValue();

    if (userObject != null &&
        userObject.nodeType == mxConstants.NODETYPE_ELEMENT)
    {
        userObject.removeAttribute(name);
    }
};
```

Comment: Do u mean like this.

Comment: ```  var th = cell.getAttribute(firstName)
             th.removeAttribute() ```

Answer (score 1):

First getIndex of:

```
mxCell.prototype.getIndex = function(name)
```

Then delete using index:

```
mxCell.prototype.remove = function( index )
```